# Graph: True or false: "$G$ is a $r$-partite graph iff $\chi(G)=r$"

Tags: graph-theory

I was thinking about a proposition, but I don't know if it's true or not. So is it true that

> $G$ is a $r$-partite graph if and only if $\chi(G)=r$ ?

$\chi(G)$ is the minimum color we need to color the graph $G$. I know that for $r=2$ it's true, but is it true for $r>2$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is true. Incidentally, people use $r$-partite instead of $r$-colorable because of that reason. (By $r$-partite, here I assume you mean *exactly* $r$-partite)

Comment: thanks for your answer :-)

Comment: @ClementC. This is not true, there's a difference between $r$-colorable and $r$-chromatic.

Comment: By *exactly*, I did mean it's not (r-1)-partite.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. What is certainly true is that if $\chi(G)=r$, then $G$ is $r$-partite.

However, [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipartite_graph), a multipartite graph does *not* require that there be edges between different parts. For example, the complete graph $K_{2,3}$ on vertex set $\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ is certainly bipartite, but it is also tripartite by taking tripartition $\{a_1,a_2\}$, $\{b_1,b_2\}$ and $\{b_3\}$. Similarly it is $4$-partite, etc.

More generally, *every* loopless graph on $n$ vertices is $n$-partite by taking each part to consist of one vertex, but certainly most graphs on $n$ vertices satisfy $\chi(G)<n$.

So in the other direction, all you can say is that if $G$ is $r$-partite, then $\chi(G)\leq r$. Put another way, $\chi(G)$ can be defined to be the minimum $r$ such that $G$ is $r$-partite.

Comment: Sorry, I was confusing with my terms (I'm not english). A $k-$partite graph $G=(V,E)$ is a graph such that $\{A_1,...,A_k\}$ where $A_i\subset V $ is a partition of $V$ where all $A_i$ are independent and such that for all $i\neq j$ there exists $e\in E$ such that an endpoint is in $A_i$ and  the other one is $A_j$. In your case, there is no edges from $\{b_1,b_2\}$ and $\{b_3\}$, therefore it can't be tripartite.

Comment: @Surb, but that is *not* the definition of $k$-partite: there is no requirement that there must be edges between different parts. Perhaps your definition should be called something like a "minimally $k$-partite graph."

Comment: @Surb Actually come to think of it, even your definition shouldn't be called "minimal". Consider the path of length $3$, say $a_1-b-c-a_2$. Then according to your definition this graph is tripartite since there is the tripartition $\{\{a_1,a_2\}, \{b\},\{c\}\}$, but of course it is also bipartite.

Comment: To solve definition problems: Is for you the graph $G$ with $V=\{1, 2\}\cup \{A\}$ and $E=\big\{\{1,A\}\big\}$ bipartite or not ?

Comment: @Surb So $G$ consists of a single edge and one isolated vertex? Then yes it is bipartite (and also tripartite), but not $1$-partite.

Comment: Ok, then your answer is correct (with your definition), but it's not my definition of bipartite (or $k-$partite graph). So with your definition, the OP statement would be: "$G$ is a complete $r-$partite graph iff $\chi(G)=r$" and the answer is **yes** :-)

Comment: @surb With your definition, the OP statement is false as well, as my previous counterexample (path of length 3) shows.

Comment: @Surb This is the first time I see the $k$-partite graph required to have edges between partitions. In fact I consider a set of isolated vertices a valid counterexample for $r=2$. Where did your definition come from?